# Is there a diagonalizable matrix $A \neq B$ such that $e^A = e^B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-exponential

> Is there a diagonalizable matrix $A \neq B$ such that $e^A = e^B$?

My initial thought was that if this is possible, then
$$
e^A e^{-A} = e^B e^{-A}
$$
so
$$
I = e^B e^{-A}.
$$
This means the statement is true if there exists a nonzero matrix $C$ such that $e^C = I$. But is this possible? My intuition tells me no, but how can it be proved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by diagonalizability, you mean diagonalizability over $\Bbb C$ of real (or complex) matrices, we have
$$\exp \pmatrix{0 & -2 \pi k \\ 2 \pi k & 0} = I_2$$ for all integers $k$.

On the other hand, if one insists on diagonalizability over $\Bbb R$ of real matrices, the answer is no, as for any real diagonal matrix $\Delta$ with diagonal entries $\lambda_a$, $\exp \Delta$ is diagonal, with diagonal entries $\exp \lambda_a$, so $\exp \Delta = I$ implies that $\Delta = 0$.

It follows from the transcendence of $\pi$ and the fact that $\ker(\exp: \Bbb C \to \Bbb C) = \{2 \pi i k : k \in \Bbb Z\}$ that there are no examples of *rational* matrices diagonalizable over $\Bbb C$ with the claimed property.

Answer (score 2):

You can have the $1\times 1$ matrices $[0],[2\pi i]$.

Comment: Helpful. This could also be generalized to any finite dimensional space by taking any diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $2 \pi i$, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the $2 \times 2$ matrices $I=\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array} \right]$ and $J=\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{array} \right]$, compare $aI+bJ$ and $aI+(b+2\pi k)J$ for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: It is simpler to just compare $I $ and $2\pi J $.

Comment: sure. You can set $a=0$ if you want.

Comment: In fact $e^I $ is not $I $, you want just 0.

Comment: @Ian But, $IJ=JI$ so, $exp(aI+bJ) = exp(aI)exp(bJ) = exp(aI)exp((b+2\pi k)J) = exp(aI+(b+2\pi k)J)$. Granted, I don't need the $aI$ term, but, I included it to have a bit different looking example. These matrices are diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$. Of course, $aI+bJ$ is just the real Jordan form of the matrix $\left[ \begin{array}{cc} a+ib & 0 \\ 0 & a-ib \end{array}\right]$.

Comment: Ah, I see where you were going with it, it is just slightly messier than what I expected. Carry on.

Comment: @Ian no problem, I have weird ideas sometimes, feel the pain of my students.